# Using Qt creator as the IDE for editing and building a project hosted on a virtual machine

Tags: ide, qt-creator, cross-compiling

Currently I'm developing a pure C++ application in a virtual machine. My editor on virtual machine is VIM. But I want to use Qt creator as IDE.  I tried `ssh -X` for running Qt creator on virtual machine. But it ran too slow to work with.
The process is too simple. I want to have source code in both machines. In local machine and virtual machine. Then I send modifications from local machine to virtual machine and when I press build button in Qt creator, a build script is executed in virtual machine to build the project. Output from virtual machine will be displayed in Qt Creator output panel.
For this purpose should I create a Qt Creator plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have a network that is connecting the two machines or not (local and virtual). If you have a network then you need to just share the project folder. In case you are using RedHat/CentOS/Fedora you can follow this link:

http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-setup-nfs-server-in-linux/

For Ubuntu you can always find a way too.

local machine should be the server and virtual machine should be the client.

In case the local machine is windows, then it would be easier, just follow this link:
http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001636.htm

Comment: Thank you but in when sharing, compiling takes place in local machine again.

Comment: Make two profiles Debug/Release or any profile you want. You can configure each machine to compile different profile if you want to avoid conflicts if any